# Possibility of using same AVD for different applications?

Tags: android

Is it possible to use same AVD(Android Virtual Device) for different applications in ECLIPSE IDE ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, provided that your avd meets min api level requirement

Answer (score 0):

Yes...

Your AVD is a virtual device...

You can run all the applications you have on your IDE if your device supports them.

Obviosly your AVD needs to have one api level >= of your application api level.